# Android - new app launch icon not rendering

Tags: android

I placed a new launch icon in the 4 folders and called it ic_launcher.png for the 4 different resolutions, and I have this in my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
```

But when I run the app, I still get the default launch icon showing up. Is there something else that I have to do that I am forgetting?

Thanks!

Comment: replace the `@drawable/ic_launcher` with `@drawable/your_new_icon_name`

Comment: make sure you have new ic_launcher file in all the drawable folders.

Comment: Did you clean the project ??? Goto Project -> clean in eclipse

Comment: @Parth Doshi but my icon name is the same as the original icon - I replaced the new one with the older one.

Comment: ok then u need to stick to the `ic_launcher` itself. I feel it's better to use some other name so that you don't get confused.

Comment: @Girish Nair just cleaned and ran it...didn't work :(

Comment: @Genadinik Try using a fresh new emulator or running it on an actual device :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the icon in all 4 drawable folders and refresh the 'res' folder. Right click on it --> 'Refresh'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the old version of your app from the device, then run it again and it will render